# Is there a way to getApplicationContext in my activity ( for a recycler view app)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

**here is my problem**

It's saying that it needs a firebase context, here is what android studio said;

> Required type: com.google.firebase.database.core.Context
> Provided: android.content.Context

**this is the onstart method, the error is in viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext......**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class, R.layout.row, ViewHolder.class, mRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int i) {

                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());

                }
            };
```

*NOTE: this activity is not a fragment, it's a normal activity*

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;

public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;

}

public void setDetails (Context ctx, String title, String description, String image){

    TextView mTitleView = mView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTV);
    TextView mDetailTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTV);
    ImageView mImageTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);

    mTitleView.setText(title);
    mDetailTv.setText(description);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageTv);


}
}
```

Comment: You used the wrong import in the ViewHolder class for Context probably or post your `ViewHolder`

Comment: error: incompatible types: android.content.Context cannot be converted to com.google.firebase.database.core.Context
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
                     this is the error I got while running my app

Comment: You did not read my comment?

Comment: i will add it now, thank you

Comment: i didn't notice it, sorry

Comment: Pro tip: You don't have to pass the context when you have a view already. Just use the context form the View. eg: `mView.getContext()`

Comment: oh my god, tysm it worked.I changed it to this and it worked;    viewHolder.setDetails(viewHolder, model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have to pass the context because I already had a view. So I replaced `getApplicationContext` with the `viewHolder`.

here is the final code;

```
viewHolder.setDetails(viewHolder, model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
```

**thanks to OhhhThatVarun for his amazing help/pro tip **